# How delete Pages in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to delete multiple or all pages in the `UIPageViewController`?

In my situation I navigate back to the `UIPageViewController` after deleting some pages/entries and I want to set only one already created Page.

I can't create all pages and save their references because of the big number of pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to delete. A UIPageViewController doesn't have any pages other than the one whose view is showing right now. It merely calls its data source asking for the next or previous page. If you don't want the user to be able to navigate to any other pages, don't supply a next or previous page: return `nil` from those data source methods.

Comment: but when I navigate back with only one entry in my data source and swipe left `viewControllerBeforeViewController` won't be called and I have two times the same entry

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. But you didn't show any code, so who knows what you're doing? There is one way to do it right, and I've told you what it is; there are a million ways to do it wrong, and I'm not going to waste time guessing which of those you're doing.

Comment: yeah sorry I am new here. I hope I formulated my problem better in this post :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083297/how-navigate-back-to-a-deleted-pageviewcontroller-entry-change-the-pageviewcon

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

`pageViewController.setViewControllers([theViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`